# 2-quotient of integer partition

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, modular-representation-theory, kac-moody-algebras

This question is mostly about understanding the notation used in the following article:
[Alex Eskin, Andrei Okounkov, *Pillowcases and quasimodular forms*, in: Victor Ginzburg (ed.), *Algebraic Geometry and Number Theory in Honor of Vladimir Drinfeld's 50th Birthday*, Birkhäuser 2006](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=gGUTVxVieRIC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=2+quotient+of+a+balanced+partition&source=bl&ots=ZjzWEKbbd_&sig=ACfU3U0LWv7OxdVEjvwqc2qil4Qir3UrOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfnYOjg5HnAhWFWisKHfc6CasQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=2%20quotient%20of%20a%20balanced%20partition&f=false).

page 8 about the 2-quotients of a partition. It claims that every partition ${\bf{\lambda}}:=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,)$ has two partitions 
$\bf{\alpha, \beta}$ such that

$$\Big\{\lambda_i -1 +1/2\Big\}=\Big\{\alpha_i -i+1/2 +\bar{p}_0(\lambda) \Big\}\sqcup \Big\{\beta_i -i+1/2+\bar{p}_0(\lambda) \Big\} $$

I mostly interested in balanced partition so I can forget about $\bar{p}_0(\lambda) $. I don't understand what is the definition of $\alpha_i, \beta_i$. Is it related to Frobenius coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ refer to heights in the Russian way to describe Young diagrams (rotate the English notation 135 degrees), this makes it into a piecewise linear function, and this interpretation has a few nice applications.

Information regarding quotients, (and its relation to character values in particular), can [be found here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/borderStripTableaux.htm).
There is the article

*Olivier Brunat and Rishi Nath. Cores and quotients of partitions through the Frobenius symbol. ArXiv e-prints, 2019.*

which apparently does what the title suggest, in case the Frobenius description of partitions is relevant.